# The image's information and thumbnail are stored in different database?

Tags: android

I use the following code to get thumbnail and fill them in gridView.
I guess that the image's information such `as BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA and MediaStore.Images.Media._ID` are stored in a database,
and the thumbnail of the image are stored in another database.

So if I want to delete a image, I need to delete three parts, the one is physical file, the two is the record of the image's information in a database, and the three is the recodr of thumbnail in another database, right?
The following code  is only to delete two parts, the one is physical file, the two is the record of the image's information in a database. How can I delete the record of thumbnail? Thanks!

BTW, the code

> sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
>   Uri.parse("file://" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

is not very good, because it's asynchronous, I need to get the latest thumbnails at once after I delete a image.

And more, will

> sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
>   Uri.parse("file://" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())))

update both the image's information database and thumbnails database ?

```
private void FillImageAndThumb() {
    this.count = curPublic.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count]; 
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    this.myID=new int[this.count];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        curPublic.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = curPublic.getInt(curPublic.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        int dataColumnIndex =curPublic.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        myID[i]=id;
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                          getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), 
                          id,
                          MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, 
                          null);
        arrPath[i] = curPublic.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
}   

private void SetCurPublic(AdapterView<?> arg0,int index){
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    };

    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    if (index==0){
        curPublic = getContentResolver().query(
            images,
                projection,
                "",          
                null,   
                ""   
                );
    }else{
        String s=arg0.getSelectedItem().toString();
        curPublic=  getContentResolver().query(
                images,
                projection,           
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME+"=?", 
                new String[]{s},         
                "" // Ordering
                );
    } 
}


public void DeleteSelected() {
    for (int i = 0; i < thumbnailsselection.length; i++) {
        if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
            File fdelete = new File(arrPath[i]);
            if (fdelete.exists()) {
                if (fdelete.delete()) {
                    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    String mSelectionClause = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
                            + "=?";
                    String[] mSelectionArgs = { String.valueOf(myID[i]) };
                    getContentResolver().delete(
                            images,
                            mSelectionClause, 
                            mSelectionArgs
                            );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could change `DeleteSelected()` from a method to an AsyncTask and perform all your delete from there in the background, which will allow the file system delete as well.